# How to use Max function with Where conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing code to select the maximum value from a column that does not equal two other large values. The maximum will always be the 3rd largest value. The two largest values are place holders, (int) in year month format 999912, and 999901.

I have tried using Max and Filter together with no luck.

```
val maxSurvey = s.max("SurveyMonth").filter(survey("SurveyMonth") =!= "999912" && survey("SurveyMonth") =!= "999901")
```

I expect the current result to be 201902.

Comment: try `s.filter($"SurveyMonth" != ""999912" && $"SurveyMonth") != "999901").max($"SurveyMonth")`

Answer (score 1):

You need select the max, but your code is wrong in the filter too, if you need Max, why you compare SurveyMonth with a String?

After changes your code will look like:

```
val maxSurvey = s.filter('SurveyMonth =!= 999912 && 'SurveyMonth =!= 999901).select(max('SurveyMonth))
```

Comment: you can use 'column_name when you need refer a column